# Managing data with CakePHP Schema and Migrations

Tags: cakephp, migration, schema

I understand how cake schema management works in terms of generating, creating, updating, dumping, etc.  My question is how do I properly maintain versions of my data as well as the table structures when doing migrations?  Obviously, when an old schema is created, for example, tables are dropped and recreated, resulting in data to be lost.  Perhaps this is not a cakephp specific question, but what is the best way to manage/protect your data versions while still having a robust way to fallback to different versions of your schema?  Is it just assumed that I make regular backups/exports of my db?  Is there a way to programmatically use the before/after methods to pull-in existing data and restore that data when schemas are created?  I know there is code to insert rows, but I couldn't realistically keep creating that for an ever-changing, large db.

Understandably, data in removed columns/tables cannot be restored, but I'm new to this and trying to wrap my brain around the concept of not losing data in tables/columns that remain the same when creating schemas with cakephp.  Thanks for any cakephp specific workflows for managing schemas+data or any other generic advice for this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [CakeDC migrations plugin](https://github.com/cakedc/migrations) instead. It won't drop the whole DB and keeps a migration file per migration. **But** migrations are **not** thought to preserve your data by default, they're changing the schema and when you drop fields or change field it is expected that data gets dropped or changed. **You** are in charge to create backups.

**Migration tools are no backup tools.**

An application should be deployed through some script or have at least some script that can be triggered to create a backup of the database *before* a migration is executed. No matter what program (Liquibase for example) or CakePHP plugin you use. Best practice is it to make a DB backup before any new version is deployed, even when no migration is involved. Not just migrations can change the DB but a bug that messed up your price calculations for example can cause a mess as well.

The migrations plugin and the schema shell offer before and after callbacks. You can implement your custom logic there to trigger an external bash script via shell_exec() to backup your DB in the before callbacks. [See the callbacks for the migration plugin here](https://github.com/CakeDC/migrations/blob/master/Docs/Documentation/Migrations.md#callbacks).

Comment: Thank you.  I need to build a strong before() approach.  When you say CakeDC uses separate migration files, is this different from cake schema generate -s  (create snapshot files)?